# Accidental intrusion into military airspace

Tags: european-union, germany, military, drones

Welcome to Germany, where we have Military installations designated as "Militärischer Sperrbezirk" (MSB), that are closed to the public. For example, a shooting range or training ground is such a MSB, as are many other installations or parts of bases. The fact that they are MSB means, that entering them is illegal as a Misdemeanor under [OWiG § 114](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/owig_1968/__114.html). But every MSB is, by virtue of being a military installation, also automatically surrounded by 100 meters of No-Fly-Zone for drones based on [LuftVO §21h](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvo_2015/__21h.html). Atop that, [StGB § 109G](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__109g.html) bans photography of military installations, and that is just the tip of the iceberg...

Now, Hapless Alice is traveling the countryside and stops with her Van at the Steinhuder Meer, a lake close to Hannover. Letting her drone with camera fly, she ends up flying it over one of the runways of the [Wunstorf Military Air Base](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fliegerhorst_Wunstorf), filming the travel and some planes that are taxiing. However, Alice is unlucky and as she gathers her drone, she is greeted by a few *friendly* Military policemen, who take her drone, her cellphone, and her into custody.

**What is the maximum punishment Alice can get jailed for?**

Comment: Is there circumstantial evidence of espionage? Is there circumstantial evidence of a dangerous interference with air traffic?

Comment: @Roland right questions - taxying airplanes are part of air traffic iirc, and you may assume Alice can be found at least recklessly providing information, if it helps.

Comment: Dangerous interference with air traffic can be punished with up to 10 years jail: https://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/315.html I think as described it would be at most a less serious case, which has a maximum sentence of up to 5 years. If Alice didn't directly interfer with a flying plane, I doubt that this is dangerous interference and believe Alice can expect a fine of up to 50,000 €. I'm not writing an answer because I haven't checked all potentially relevant laws.

Comment: *Hapless Alice* should also be aware that the same action will cause probems in most countries of the world.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the maximum punishment Alice can get jailed for?

Probably no jail term at all.

An '**Accidental** intrusion into military airspace' would not be considered a fullment of the major condition defined in [§109g (1 and 2) StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1217): 'thereby **knowingly endangers** the security of the Federal Republic of Germany', which is the only law listed in the question that contains a possible jail sentence.

---

**Note**: this answer will **not deal** with the 'and that is just the tip of the iceberg...' part of the question, since it is only speculation. An answer (just as a *public prosecutor* would) can only deal with **known facts**.

- [§114 OWiG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_owig/englisch_owig.html#p0685)

  - may **possibly** be sanctioned by a fine

    - no jail term possible
- [§21h LuftVO](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvo_2015/__21h.html)

  - can be fined up to €50000

    - no jail term possible
- [§109g StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1217)

  - a penalty of imprisonment for a term not exceeding 2 (number 2) or 5 (number 1) years or a fine.

    - a jail term (or fine) is possible if all conditions are fulfilled, the major condition being:

      - *and thereby **knowingly endangers** the security of the Federal Republic of Germany*

It would be for a judge to deside whether *Hapless Alice* action was so **severe** to warrant a jail term instead of a fine.

Of course the possiblity exists that the public prosecutor came to the conclusion that *Hapless Alice* simply forgot to turn her brain on before driving through the countryside. But that would be more of a matter that the StVG or StVO deals with.

---

**Sources**:

- [Act on Regulatory Offences (OWiG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_owig/index.html)

  - [Act on Regulatory Offences (OWiG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_owig/index.html)

    - [§114 - Entering Military Installations](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_owig/englisch_owig.html#p0685)

      - (2) The regulatory offence **may** be sanctioned by a regulatory fine.
- [Luftverkehrs-Ordnung (LuftVO)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvo_2015/index.html) (German only)

  - [§21h - Regelungen für den Betrieb von unbemannten Fluggeräten in geografischen Gebieten nach der Durchführungsverordnung (EU) 2019/947 (LuftVO)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvo_2015/__21h.html)

    - [§44 - Ordnungswidrigkeiten (LuftVO)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvo_2015/__44.html)

      - 17d.
        entgegen § 21h Absatz 3 und 4 ein unbemanntes Fluggerät betreibt,

        - §58 Absatz 1 Nummer 10 des Luftverkehrsgesetzes (LuftVG)
- [Luftverkehrsgesetz – (LuftVG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvg/) (German only)

  - [Straf- und Bußgeldvorschriften: §58](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvg/__58.html)

  > (3) Die Ordnungswidrigkeit nach Absatz 1 Nummer 2, 3, 9, 12, 12a und 16 kann mit einer Geldbuße bis zu zehntausend Euro, die Ordnungswidrigkeit nach Absatz 1 Nummer 5 bis 7 und 13 mit einer Geldbuße bis zu dreißigtausend Euro, die Ordnungswidrigkeit nach **Absatz 1** Nummer 1, 1a, 4, 8, 8a, **10**, 11, 14, 15, 18 und 19 sowie nach Absatz 2 mit einer Geldbuße **bis zu fünfzigtausend Euro** geahndet werden.
  >
  > > (3) The administrative offense according to paragraph 1 numbers 2, 3, 9, 12, 12a and 16 can be punished with a fine of up to ten thousand euros, the administrative offense according to paragraph 1 numbers 5 to 7 and 13 can be punished with a fine of up to thirty thousand euros,  Administrative offenses pursuant to **paragraph 1** numbers 1, 1a, 4, 8, 8a, **10**, 11, 14, 15, 18 and 19 as well as paragraph 2 are punishable by a fine **up to fifty thousand euros**.
- [German Criminal Code (Strafgesetzbuch – StGB)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/index.html)

  - [§109g - Images endangering national security](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1217)

    - *... and thereby **knowingly endangers** the security of the Federal Republic of Germany ...*

Comment: Why do you ignore StGB §315?